# In R, how can I properly subset a data frame based on a list of values inside of a function?

Tags: r, parsing, dataframe, subset, eval

I have a function that is attempting to select rows from a dataframe based on a list of values.

For instance, some values might be:

```
> subset_ids
[1] "JUL_0003_rep1" "JUL_0003_rep2"
[3] "JUL_0003_rep3" "JUL_0007_rep1"
[5] "JUL_0007_rep2" "JUL_0007_rep3"
```

I have a data frame called "targets" with a column called "LongName".  It has many other columns but no big deal.  I want to select the rows from targets when LongName is in subset ids.

I can do this fine with either:

```
targets[is.element(targets$LongName, subset_ids),]
```

or

```
targets[targets$LongName %in% subset_ids,]
```

The problem is that I want to do this in a function, and I don't know what the column will be called in advance.

So I tried using the eval/parse method, which upon recent reading may not be the best way to do it.  When I do the following:

```
sub1 <- paste("targets[is.element(targets$", column_name, ", subset_ids),]", sep="")
targets_subset <- as.character(eval(parse(text = sub1)))
```

It returns some strange concatenation of row numbers.  It looks like this:

```
[1] "c(5, 6, 7, 17, 18, 19, 26, 27, 28, 35, 36, 46, 47, 48, 54, 55, 61, 62, 63, 64, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 91, 92, 93, 102, 103, 104, 114, 117, 118, 129, 136, 137, 140, 141, 151, 152, 153, 157, 158, 159, 169, 172, 173, 183, 187, 188, 199, 200, 201, 208, 209, 210, 232, 233, 241, 242, 243, 252, 253, 254, 264, 265, 270, 271, 285, 286, 296, 297, 298)"
[2] "c(5, 6, 7, 17, 18, 19, 26, 27, 28, 35, 36, 46, 47, 48, 54, 55, 61, 62, 63, 64, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 91, 92, 93, 102, 103, 104, 114, 117, 118, 129, 136, 137, 140, 141, 151, 152, 153, 157, 158, 159, 169, 172, 173, 183, 187, 188, 199, 200, 201, 208, 209, 210, 232, 233, 241, 242, 243, 252, 253, 254, 264, 265, 270, 271, 285, 286, 296, 297, 298)"
[3] "c(3, 3, 3, 7, 7, 7, 11, 11, 11, 15, 15, 19, 19, 19, 22, 22, 26, 26, 27, 27, 31, 31, 31, 32, 32, 32, 39, 39, 39, 43, 43, 43, 47, 49, 49, 53, 57, 57, 59, 59, 63, 63, 63, 65, 65, 65, 70, 72, 72, 76, 78, 78, 83, 83, 83, 86, 86, 86, 97, 97, 100, 100, 100, 104, 104, 104, 108, 108, 111, 111, 117, 117, 121, 121, 121)"
```

So 5, 6, 7, 17 ... appear to be the right rows for the target i'm trying to pick, but I don't understand why it sent this back in the first place, or what item [3] is at all.

If I manually execute the line generated by the above "sub1 <- ...", then it returns the proper data.  If I ask the function to do it, it returns this garbage.

My question is two-fold.  1: Why is the data being returned this way? 2: Is there a better way than eval/parse to do what I'm trying to do?

I suspect some strange scope or environment level issue, but it is unclear to me at this point.  I appreciate any advice anyone has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data are returned that way because you are coercing the dataframe to a character object. Try

```
as.character(head(targets))
```

to see a short example.

So, your method works if you eliminate the `as.character()`. Here it is as a MWE:

```
targets <- data.frame(LongName = sample(letters, 1000, replace = TRUE),
                      SeqNum= 1:1000,
                      X = rnorm(1000))
subset_ids <- c("a","f")

targets[is.element(targets$LongName, subset_ids),]

targets[targets$LongName %in% subset_ids,]

testfun <- function(targets, column_name, subset_ids){
  sub1 <- paste("targets[is.element(targets$", column_name, ", subset_ids),]", sep="")
  targets_subset <- eval(parse(text = sub1))

  return(targets_subset)
}

testfun(targets, column_name = "LongName", subset_ids)
```